# How to Store list in String in sqflite flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am using sqflite  package for local Storage I need to store list of json in String, then Particular String again I need reconvert into Json list.

Comment: Please present your best effort. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(UPDATE: How to store List<String> data type in sqflite) sqflite error: DatabaseException(java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514027/update-how-to-store-liststring-data-type-in-sqflite-sqflite-error-database)

Answer (score 1):

json

```
{
     "images": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "img1"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "img2"
        }
      ]
}
```

Convert

```
import 'dart:convert';
final data = {
     "images": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "img1"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "img2"
        }
      ],
};
final String dataAsJson = json.encode(data);
```

Inserting Data after opening database

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
await db.insert(
    'images', # the name of the table
    {'data': dataAsJson}, # `data` is the column's name
);
```

Getting Data

```
final List<Map> maps = await db.query('images', columns: ['id', 'data']);
final dataFromJsonToMap = json.decode(maps[0]);
```